# MySQL connection doesn't work anymore

Tags: mysql, php

I had two MySQL servers running (127.0.0.1:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3307). Now I get this strange error: `mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'` I can connect with `localhost:3307`, but there aren't any tables/databases. I'm fairly sure `/etc/my.cnf` is right:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = root
password   = ***

[mysqld]
port       = 3306
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld2]
port       = 3307
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

What can I do now? How can I sanely restart the MySQL server?

Perhaps more importantly:

How can I make sure all the tables still exist?

Comment: Where can you connect with localhost:3307? In a php app?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one thing I quickly see is missing : [Each [mysqld] needs to have its own datadir](http://www.pythian.com/news/1144/using-mysqld_multi-to-manage-multiple-servers/). No two mysqld groups can share the same datadir. You need to allocate different datadirs in different folders and make sure you run "chown -R mysql:mysql (datadir folder)" on all datadirs.

Your /etc/my.cnf should look something like this:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = root
password   = ***

[mysqld]
port       = 3306
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql1
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld2]
port       = 3307
datadir  = /var/lib/mysql2
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

[Check out this link from the Pythian Group on how to start and stop the individual DB services](http://www.pythian.com/news/1144/using-mysqld_multi-to-manage-multiple-servers/).

From my answer, you should see that there must be a complete copy of the data in /var/lib/mysql1, /var/lib/mysql2, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I run multis:

1. Make a "my.cnf" for each instance of mysql specifying your port and socket.
   e.g. Port 3307

   [mysqld]

   port      = 3307

   socket    = /opt/db/3307/mysql.sock

   datadir   = /opt/db/3307

   tmpdir    = /opt/tmp/3307

   ...
2. Start each instance using its own include file.

e.g.

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my_3306.cnf
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my_3307.cnf
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my_3308.cnf
```

This way I can control each individual instance.

Comment: I've tested with only `port` and `datadir` and they seem to work fine. Is setting the `socket` and `tmpdir` required?

Comment: In my experience, the socket is required. However, you should have separate everything so you can track down problems.