# mysqlservice command syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL.

I've found myself in the position of having two different versions running on one host.

I'm a little unsure of how these are working together.  Do I issue `>service mysqlservice 3307 start`?

Where does `mysql3307` come into play?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a lot like something I created back in February 2011. In fact, I placed the code for the `mysqlservice` script in one post : [Running multiple instances on the same host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host/6375#6375) (Sep 30, 2011)

The mysqlservice script is a quasi-service I created to help set up multiple mysql instances. The idea is to create

- my.cnf for a specific port number
- service filename to launch the service

In this case, you should see a file called `/etc/init.d/mysql3307`. If you do not have one, please create it. It should look like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# readahead:    Prereads programs required for startup into memory
#
# chkconfig: 2345 4 99
# description:  This service causes the programs used during startup \
#               to be loaded into memory before they are needed,\
#               thus improving startup performance
#
#

# Sanity checks.
[ -x /usr/sbin/readahead ] || exit 0

# Check for > 384 MB
#free -m | gawk '/Mem:/ {exit ($2 >= 384)?0:1}' || exit 0

# Source function library.
#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

WHICH=/usr/bin/which
SERVICE=`${WHICH} service`

MYSQL=`${WHICH} mysql`
PORT_NUMBER=3307

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
    start)      ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} start    ;;
    stop)       ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} stop     ;;
    status)     ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} status   ;;
    restart)    ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} restart  ;;
    mycnf)      ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} mycnf    ;;
    edit)       ${SERVICE} mysqlservice ${PORT_NUMBER} edit     ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status|mycnf}"
        ;;
esac
```

After creating the file, please run

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/mysql3307
```

Now, the service can be summoned with

```
service mysql3307 start
```

Under the hood, it will call

```
service mysqlservice 3307 start
```

You could call it that way as well. Yet, setting up /etc/init.d/mysql3307 makes the service have a name that's easy to remember.

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : You have to create a my.cnf file for port 3307 called `/etc/my3307.cnf`

The file `/etc/my3307.cnf` must include

```
[mysqld]
port=3307
datadir=<whatever folder you have for 3307's mysql instance>
```

The fundamentals difference between services are

- datadir
- port number

You can start and stop the services independent of each other. While [`mysqld_multi`](http://www.pythian.com/news/1144/using-mysqld_multi-to-manage-multiple-servers/) allows you to have multiple MySQL Instances under one my.cnf via setting up mysqld groups, I created the `mysqlservice` quasi-service to use distinct my.cnf files for each instance. That way, you do not have to worry setting up my.cnf to know  what is common to all MySQL Instances vs. what is unique to each MySQL Instance.

If you setup more than two services in this manner, you become responsible for assigning the proper amount of RAM for buffers, caches, and threads.