# MySQL customized service script for zip installation

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, startup, shutdown

We are currently using MySQL 5.7.20 on CentOS and are using zip installation.
Since it is a zip installation we do not have service created in /etc/init.d/.

Is there any other method for auto-startup and auto-shutdown as we usually do with service.

We can startup using /etc/rc.local but what about if we want to do auto-shutdown or service status? any sample service script

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SHUTDOWN

MySQL 5.7 now features the [SHUTDOWN command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/shutdown.html), which requiresthe  [SHUTDOWN privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_shutdown).

#### SHUTDOWN METHOD #1: Within [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)

```
mysql> SHUTDOWN;
```

#### SHUTDOWN METHOD #2: From OS using [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)

```
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -P3306 --protocol=tcp"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"SHUTDONW"
```

#### SHUTDOWN METHOD #3: Using [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)

This can be done with any MySQL 5.x version

```
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -P3306 --protocol=tcp"
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} shutdown
```

## STATUS

You can use [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)

For example, to see if mysqld is alive, run this:

```
MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS} -P3306 --protocol=tcp"
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} ping 2>/dev/null | grep "mysqld is alive"
```

You can also do one of the following:

```
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} status
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} variables
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} uptime
mysqladmin ${MYSQL_CONN} processlist
```

## AUTO START

Make sure you have `chkconfig mysqld on` or  `chkconfig mysql on` enabled

There are no mysql utility programs to auto-startup except for [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html), which is launched by the mysqld (or mysql) service. This is usually issued by `sudo service mysqld start` (MySQL 5.7) or `sudo service mysql start`.

If you would like to attempt to write a custom mysqld_safe script, please see my old posts for ideas

- `Sep 30, 2011` : [Running multiple instances on the same host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host/6375#6375)
- `Sep 17, 2012` : [mysqlservice command syntax](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24438/mysqlservice-command-syntax/24439#24439)

Comment: Thank you so much and great answer as always, you are the king of MySQL..