# MySql - set my.cnf location at server start

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, configuration

I want to have two MySql servers running on the same system (for master-slave replication tests purposes).
To be able to do this I need both servers read different `my.cnf` files.
As I see at startup MySql tries to read from one of default locations.
How can I specify it own `my.cnf` location for MySql server?

PS.
I am about to use MySql 5.6 under Debian environment.

Answer (score 1):

mysqld_multi is designed to manage several mysqld processes that listen for connections on different Unix socket files and TCP/IP ports. It can start or stop servers, or report their current status.

These links can be helpful to you
[Running multiple instances on the same host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html