# mysqld-multi with first DB as Slave and second DB as Master

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysqld-multi

Yesterday, I setup mysqld-multi in my.cnf. It works fantastic, but there is still a further Problem.

The first DB on socket 1 running as Slave from a other server. The second one from socket 2 should run as Master for a further Slave. The replication for DB 1 running successful.

**My question is it possible to setup the master-slave environment for every socket?
Is it basically possible to setup more than one master-slave configuration in my.cnf?**

I couldn't found helpful hints in google or I doesn't have the correct search words.

I'm happy for any helpful hints.

My system is Debian 6 with mysql 5 and php.

```
[mysqld1] read-only # comment out only on the productive 
dbmaster port = 3306 
datadir = /var/lib/mysql 
pid-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid 
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
user = mysql 
log-error=/var/log/mysql1.log 
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql 
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysqlinnolog 
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/master-relay-bin 
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/master-relay-bin.index 
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/relaylog/master-bin

[mysqld2] 
port = 3307 
datadir = /var/lib/mysql-data2/mysqld2 
pid-file = /var/lib/mysql-data2/mysqld2/mysql.pid 
socket = /var/lib/mysql-data2/mysqld2/mysql.sock 
user = mysql 
log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log 
log-bin = /var/log/data2/mysql-bin
```

Both instance have a specific port and a separate Datadir. Is it possible to give each section in the snippet a unique ID? Can I put the Slave ID in section `[mysqld1]` and the master ID in `[mysqld2]`?

Comment: Can you explain your second question ("Is it basically possible to setup more than one master-slave configuration in my.cnf"?) more as all the servers running will be using the different my.cnf

Comment: Ok basically my.cnf has a section like this: master-user = mysqlslave
server-id = 100
report-host = myslave_1...my slave get id101 .... can I move this section as option for DB1 and create a new master settings for db2?

Answer (score 1):

I address something like this back on May 31, 2011 : [MySQL connection doesn't work anymore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/mysql-connection-doesnt-work-anymore/3075#3075)

Essentailly, you must make sure each mysql instance has a unique socket file, datadir, slow log, error log, and its fair share of memory.

You could look into setting up a separate mysqld service for a specific port : [Running multiple instances on the same host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host/6375#6375)

You should make sure db2 has a unique server_id. Furthermore, if the Slave is to be a Master also, make sure you have log-slave-updates in my.cnf for this Slave.

Comment: Tanks Rolando.... the first steps are successfull but where in my.cnf can I set the unique server_id?

Comment: BIG THX Rolando ..... It works. I add the server id entry to the mysld2 section and it works. it was very easy. sorry for my stupid questions. Have a nice day....