# CREATE TABLE not issued on other masters

Tags: mysql, replication

Database is created on all multi masters.

Why CREATE TABLE doesn't being replicated to other masters.

some explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MultiMaster Replication, every DB server needs this

```
[mysqld]
log-slave-updates
```

This will [tell a Slave to log completed SQL commands from the Relay Logs into the Slave's binary logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates). Just add that option to every Slave and restart mysql.

If this does not work, you may need to explain more things to us.

Here are my other posts where I suggested using [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates)

- `Oct 09, 2013` : [Multi-master and multi slave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51285/multi-master-and-multi-slave/51291#51291)
- `Dec 05, 2012` : [MySQL Slave Relay Logging but not logging Binary Log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29828/mysql-slave-relay-logging-but-not-logging-binary-log/29833#29833)
- `May 29, 2012` : [mysqld-multi with first DB as Slave and second DB as Master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18510/mysqld-multi-with-first-db-as-slave-and-second-db-as-master/18519#18519)
- `May 07, 2012` : [Setting Circular Replication in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17529/setting-circular-replication-in-mysql/17532#17532)

## Give it a Try !!!